# Gallery Grid Slider Responsive with equal height box

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gallery

I want to create a gallery grid slider responsive with equal height boxes.

Example
650px wide and above 3 columns and 2 rows.

550px wide and below 2 columns and 3 rows.

450px wide and below 1 column and 1 row.

I have been using this jQuery plugin https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height for now.

Can I use this with an other plugin slider or there's another alternative?

```
(function() {
     /* matchHeight example */
    $(function() {
     // apply your matchHeight on DOM ready (they will be automatically re-applied on load or resize)
     var byRow = $('.item-wrapper').hasClass('match-rows');
    // apply matchHeight to each item container's items
    $('.item-container').each(function() {
        $(this).children('.item-query').matchHeight({
             byRow: byRow
        });
        });
    });
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/76cx7roy/

Answer (score 0):

Here: I used bxslider.
But the problem is not responsive changing 2 columns and 3 rows to 1 column and 1 row. It only works when its load.

```
(function() {
         /* matchHeight example */
        $(function() {
         // apply your matchHeight on DOM ready (they will be automatically re-applied on load or resize)
         var byRow = $('.item-wrapper').hasClass('match-rows');
        // apply matchHeight to each item container's items
        $('.item-container').each(function() {
            $(this).children('.item-query').matchHeight({
                 byRow: byRow
            });
            });
      if($(window).width() > 450 && !$(".bx-s").length){
        var divs = jQuery(".item-container .item-query");
          for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=6) {
            divs.slice(i, i+6).wrapAll("<div class='bx-s'></div>");
          }
      }else{
            $(".bx-s .item-query").unwrap();
      }
      $('.item-container').bxSlider({
          nextSelector: '#item-nav-right',
          prevSelector: '#item-nav-left',
          pager: false,
          nextText: 'next',
          prevText: 'prev'
        });
        });
    })();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k55y6c9h/